# can we use foreach() for two different arrays at once?

Tags: php, arrays

I am facing problem when I am trying to insert values from array to mysql database.

```
foreach ( $_POST['product_id'] as $key=>$value AND $_POST['discount'] as $key1=>$discount) { }
```

check the above given code where I am going wrong?

Comment: explain your problem plz

Comment: Proper syntax `foreach(array_expression as $key => $value)`

Comment: This is not valid syntax. To directly answer the question in te title, NO you cant do that

Comment: You can't do it like that. Try [merging](http://pl1.php.net/array_merge) your array and iterate over merged array

Comment: That won't work. It's not logical, because you are not guaranteed to have same amount of products and discounts. Can you specify more precisely, what are you trying to achiev?

Comment: i am getting variable $_POST['product_id'],$_POST['discount'] by post method and i want to insert this two array values in my mysql database.

Comment: use array_combine  function and after apply foreach.this is easy method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regular `for` loop as long as the indexes match:

```
$count = count($_POST['product_id']);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
    echo $_POST['product_id'][$i];
    echo $_POST['discount'][$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `array_map` this will loop through all keys in all arrays provided simultaneously.

```
array_map(function(){
  $args = func_get_args();
  foreach($args as $k => $v) {
    echo $v;
  }
}, $arr1, $arr2 ...);
```